# How can I stop the visual studio test controller from throwing Error during DsBind operation: 5

Tags: visualstudio, mtm

We have a test controller set up to run CodedUI tests remotely from Microsoft Test Manager. This has been running without problem for months.

However two days ago for no apparent reason (nobody was really using it at the time), its started to throw this DsBind error in the event viewer every 60 seconds. We can still run CodedUI tests remotely through the controller with no issue, however I'm trying to get the controller set up so that I can run manual tests and get test impact. That hasn't been working and so I'm trying to clean up any errors that might get in the way of that task. This is the most recent and most persistent.

I haven't managed to find much information on what causes this error either so hoping that some of you have seen it.

[image: Event viewer of Test Controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`ve stumbled onto this issue a while back.

What helped me was this answer:

"*Could you please cross check your test controller setup to make sure everything is ok  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546460.aspx
Local machine account and domain account often doesn't work well with test agent and controller. Work around for this issue is to use Lab service account. Lab service account to used to communicate with test agents. Refer this if you had like to try - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692846.aspx*"

Other fix related to this issue in case you`re using a VM:

*"I'm pretty sure, that this Problem is related to the time change task running during log-in.
I tried this ofter log-in:
The time was changed to 5/16/13 8 a.m.
1. Changing the date to a later date. I used 7/20/12
2. Starting the Build Service in the Team Foundation Server Admin Console
optional: config Build Controller and Agent
3. Running the scheduled task again (changing the date back to 5/16/12)* 
"

Hope these help!

Comment: I'll give this a try on monday and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Used the lab service account with a new test controller, getting no errors anymore! Now I'm tackling a different problem unrelated to this question